# href / anchor (jump to id) weird behavior in Github pages

Tags: javascript, html, github-pages

Please take a look at my page, https://kuncung38.github.io/portfolio-website/

When I used live server from VSCode, everything works just as expected, When I uploaded this to github pages, a weird bug appeared.

You will notice the **problem**, it has a **weird behavior** when you clicked either button, you will **have to clicked the button twice** for something to happen. Here is my code:

```
var x = document.getElementById('second-section');
var memeSection = document.getElementsByClassName("memeSection");
var seriousSection = document.getElementsByClassName("seriousSection");
var meme = document.getElementsByClassName("meme");
var serious = document.getElementsByClassName("serious");

function show() {
    x.style.display = 'block';

    Array.from(memeSection).forEach(memeSection => memeSection.style.display = 'none');
    Array.from(seriousSection).forEach(seriousSection => seriousSection.style.display = 'block');
    Array.from(meme).forEach(meme => meme.style.display = 'none');
    Array.from(serious).forEach(serious => serious.style.display = 'flex');
    window.location.href = "index.html#home";
  }

function showMeme() {
    x.style.display = 'block';

    Array.from(memeSection).forEach(memeSection => memeSection.style.display = 'block');
    Array.from(seriousSection).forEach(seriousSection => seriousSection.style.display = 'none');
    Array.from(meme).forEach(meme => meme.style.display = 'flex');
    Array.from(serious).forEach(serious => serious.style.display = 'none');
    console.log("no problem till here")
    window.location.href = "index.html#home-meme";
}
```

Basically the two buttons on the homepage have these two functions. I do not know what is wrong with my codes, You can inspect the webpage to see the full code if needed, or you can click [here](https://github.com/kuncung38/portfolio-website).

Please help me :(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you click, `index.html` is added to the URL, so effectively you navigate away from the current page. If you start out at https://kuncung38.github.io/portfolio-website/index.html the problem disappears.

A solution would be *not* to overwrite the entire `window.location.href` but only the `hash`:

```
window.location.hash = "#home";
```

That should work whether or not `index.html` is in the URL.

Comment: wuaow that works, still dont know why the problem happen, but it works, so thank you!!

Comment: When you navigate away from the page (either by hand, or through setting `window.location.href`), the page is loaded from scratch. And since the `#second-section` div has `display: none;`, the anchor `#home` in the URL does nothing if the JavaScript to un-hide the section doesn't run first.